# extending a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it's possible to extend a SQL table the same way how 'extends' works in java or any other language equivalent.

e.g - let's say we have a table named User and a table named SuperUser.
**User has (id, name, age)** and **SuperUser** should has **(id, name, age, super_power)**.
The first 3 columns are the same, only the super_power is differ. If the User table were long and complicated then it seems to be wasteful to maintain CREATE statement and manipulated it for the child table instead of using an extend functionality.

EDIT:
I would like to sharpen my dilemma, I'm only referencing the creation of the tables process and would rather understand if there's a solution that doesn't involve creating 1 to 1 relation to the extension.
e.g if I have User, and would like to have UserA, UserB and UserC. All with the same columns instead of 1 additional column. Let's complicate it - from UserB I might have UserBA, UserBB and UserBC and centra.

Comment: SQL doesn't work with extending table from another table. This is what relations between tables are for. As I see it in this example, why do you even need user table? use only superUser table and when super_power = 0 it is a normal user.

Comment: Inheritance in Relational DBs is called *1-1 relationship*.

Comment: I agree this is wrong in the first place but if you only need to get "one" table in your script then you can use UNION in your sql and set super_power to be 0 for the User SELECT.

Comment: As I said, if this is what you only need: SELECT id, name, age, 0 FROM User AS super_power UNION SELECT id, name, age, super_power FROM SuperUser;

Comment: @sagi these tables I mentioned in the questions body were only for demonstration, this isn't my usecase.

Comment: @MargaretBloom's comment - I referencing the table creation process only and would not want any effect on the schema.

Comment: So for each case there is a different solution, and there is always a solution.. but sql doesn't support extending table.. this is what the relations are for. I'll suggest updating the question to the actual problem..

Comment: thanks @sagi, that what I expected. toda raba!

Comment: PostgreSQL supports **Table Inheritance**, this might be what you want: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html